# Joomla custom fields - article archived cannot be accessed

Tags: php, joomla3.0

i have made an override for the archive com_content/views/archive/default.php
where i want to access a custom field like i did with my override of the normal
article view. But when i want to access the custom fields the
array jcfields[] is empty. There are no entries like in the article view.

anyways i have a foreach loop like this ($this->items as $i => $item)

Is there something missing? 
If you need anymore infos, please let me know!

thanxs

Answer (score 0):

i still don't unsterstand why the jcfields[] array is empty 
at an archived article.

But i found me a solution for the problem:

```
JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php');
$jcFields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_content.article', $item, true);
$array = json_decode(json_encode($jcFields), True);
$fields = [];
foreach ($array as $field) {
  array_push($fields,$field['name'],$field['value'],$field['rawvalue']);
}
```